# Filter in a list of object based on array

Tags: javascript

Question, i'm having a list of products with tags in them like the following:

```
const products = [{
    "id": 1,
    "tags": {
      "option": ["A", "B"]
    }
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "tags": {
      "option": ["B"],
      "type": ["A", "B", "C"]
    }
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "tags": {
      "type": ["A"]
    }
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "tags": {
      "option": ["B", "C"],
      "type": ["A", "C"]
    }
  }];
```

Based on checkboxes im creating the filter object like below:

```
var filter = {
  "option": [], 
  "type": []
}
```

the above will be filled fe:

```
var filter = {
  "option": ["A"], // can contain more than one value
  "type": ["C", "B"] // can contain more than one value
}
```

with this filter applied it should return the following:

```
const products = [{
    "id": 1,
    "tags": {
      "option": ["A", "B"]
    }
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "tags": {
      "option": ["B"],
      "type": ["A", "B", "C"]
    }
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "tags": {
      "option": ["B", "C"],
      "type": ["A", "C"]
    }
  }];
```

I want to check if the item contains in the product list and if so return a new product list that only contains the products that contain the added filters. Can someone give me a push in the right direction?

currently i'm trying to do a .filter() on the products object but i cannot seem to get it to work with more than 1 filter applied.

```js
const products = [{
    "id": 1,
    "tags": {
      "option": ["B", "A"]
    }
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "tags": {
      "option": ["B"],
      "type": ["A", "B", "C"]
    }
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "tags": {
      "type": ["A"]
    }
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "tags": {
      "option": ["B", "C"],
      "type": ["A", "C"]
    }
  }];

var filter = {
  "option": ["A"], 
  "type": ["C", "B"] 
}

function checkAvailability(arr, val) {
if (arr != undefined) {
  return arr.some(function(arrVal) {
      return val === arrVal;
    });
  }
}

const obj = []
const test = products.filter(product => {
  for(var i = 0; i < filter.option.length; i++) {
    return checkAvailability(product.tags.option, filter.option[i])
  }
})
console.log(test)
```

Comment: If an object contains no `option` or `type`, does it match all those filters or none of them?

Comment: Can the filter contain multiple options and/or types? Does the object have to match all of them or any of them?

Comment: Check out [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: @Barmar, if it contains none values it should return all values. if it contains more than one value it should match all of them.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comments. I'm quite new here. cause my project is in vue i need to rewrite my function a bit to get it here. I'll try to make my own attempt in plunker or something and put it here.

Comment: I've added a sample of my code (atleast how far i came with something working). but this only returns one part of my filter.

Comment: The `return` statement in the `for` loop makes it exit the function after checking `filter.option[0]`. It never checks the other filter options.

Comment: You never do anything with `filter.type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array with key and sets for the values and filter the array by checking the filter array with the values.

```js
const
    products = [{ id: 1, tags: { option: ["A", "B"] } }, { id: 2, tags: { option: ["B"], type: ["A", "B", "C"] } }, { id: 3, tags: { type: ["A"] } }, { id: 4, tags: { option: ["B", "C"], type: ["A", "C"] } }],
    filter = { option: ["A"], type: ["C", "B"] },
    filterArray = Object.entries(filter).map(([k, v]) => [k, Set.prototype.has.bind(new Set(v))]),
    result = products.filter(({ tags }) =>
        filterArray.some(([k, fn]) => (tags[k] || []).some(fn))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```